# dnsmasq use different upstream servers for specific hosts by IP

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I am trying to set up the following scenario:

Local raspberry (192.168.0.9) is used as both dhcp server (dhcpd) and dns server (dnsmasq).

I have two sets of devices (my own and everyone else's), that receive their IP addresses from specific ranges and DNS Servers specified in dhcpd.conf as this:

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 192.168.0.1;

    pool {
            deny unknown-clients;
            range 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.40;
            option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.9;

            host A {
                    hardware ethernet 11:22:33:44:55:66;
                    fixed-address 192.168.0.21;
            }
            host B {
                    hardware ethernet 66:55:44:33:22:11;
                    fixed-address 192.168.0.22;
            }
    pool {
            range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.19;
            allow unknown-clients;
            deny known-clients;
            option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
    }
}
```

That works fine. I have my own devices use dnsmasq for specific rules, ad-blocking and so on, while other clients use google's dns without restrictions.

However, I would like to

- have IP assignment done via dhcpd pools, but
- use dnsmasq as dns server for both IP address ranges
- provide every client that connects with some locally defined name resolution provided by dnsmasq entries (like 'address=/homenet_files/192.168.0.9')
- use different upstream servers for the different IP ranges in dnsmasq

example: client in IP range 192.168.0.20 - 40 should use opendns
`server=208.67.222.222` , others
`server=8.8.8.8`

Is there a way to provide different configuration files for specified IP ranges?
tbh the dnsmasq manual is over my head regarding this question. Any help appreciated.